# Django: The joined path is located outside of the base path component

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

i'm using Django 10 and i dont know why after i collect my static files successfuly, when i try to run server in deployment mode(debug=False) it occurs me something like this:

When i look for a static file by doing:  `python manage.py findstatic /static/mysite/js/javascript.js`

`django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/static/mysite/js/javascript.js) is located outside of the base path component (/home/xxxx/.venvs/mysite/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static)`

I run this using  a virtual env 'mysite'.

In **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") (i tried also just only 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/mysite/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

my **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [   
    url(r'', include('mysite.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

This is new for me, i also did already a django website and it never occurs such error. Why is not considering my STATIC_ROOT path? For the other hand the collectstatic works fine. And if i runserver with a debug a true it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findstatic`’s positional argument is the parameter you would pass to `static` to render a particular static file in a template.  The error you are seeing is because you used an absolute path and not the parameter you would pass to the `static` function in a template.  Are you sure you didn’t mean something like:

```
python manage.py findstatic mysite/js/javascript.js
```

for a file you would refer to with

```
{% static 'mysite/js/javascript.js' %}
```

or

```
python manage.py findstatic js/javascript.js
```

for a file you would refer to with

```
{% static 'js/javascript.js' %}
```

For your reference:

```
usage: manage.py findstatic [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                            [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH]
                            [--traceback] [--no-color] [--first]
                            staticfile [staticfile ...]

Finds the absolute paths for the given static file(s).

positional arguments:   staticfile
```

---

n.b., django's staticfiles app is [not supposed to be used in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).  In production, you are supposed to use a webserver to serve static files based.  e.g., for nginx, you would include [a block like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/deployment/):

```
location /static {
    root /path/to/django;
}
```

To debug your static files check your `STATIC_ROOT` directory after you run collectstatic and make sure your files are there.  If they are, make sure your webserver is configured to properly serve your static files directory.

Comment: ok my mistake,  i real can find my static files, but i don't know why  doesn't load any static file when page loads.. and i'm having some difficult to find any error log or some clue why this happen.

Comment: More info add above for you.

Comment: Thanks after search more I did remember that only with a web server running I was able to load static files.