# Django Collectstatic Suspicious File operation

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, collectstatic

I am trying to run collectstatic on heroku. When I got this error:

```
remote: 'component ({})'.format(final_path, base_path)) 
remote: django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (/tmp/build_4652acfe079723bc273763513a187201/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot) is located outside of the base path component (/tmp/build_4652acfe079723bc273763513a187201/staticfiles)
```

I thought perhaps I had missed something with collectstatic on my end, so I ran it locally, and got the exact same error.

Then I went looking. I found:

/home/malikarumi/Projects/aishah/jamf35/staticfiles/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

and

/home/malikarumi/Projects/aishah/jamf35/static/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot

My settings:

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/bootstrap/fonts/'),

There is a ticket out there, but it seems to be about paths, and I see nothing wrong with my paths, https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27201 
Another one deals with files, and might be closer to my issue, because it has to do with created tmp files, but I really can't tell:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26644

I should note that I also looked at [Django: The joined path is located outside of the base path component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350325/django-the-joined-path-is-located-outside-of-the-base-path-component),
[Django: How to allow a Suspicious File Operation / copy a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019371/django-how-to-allow-a-suspicious-file-operation-copy-a-file),  and  [Django | joined path is located outside of the base path component {% static img.thumbnail.url %}, Error 400 with whitenoise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241902/django-joined-path-is-located-outside-of-the-base-path-component-static-img), but they seem to be more about MEDIA ROOT issues.

I'm not sure what the fix is, here. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting looks odd. Are you sure you don't want this?

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
```

The problem is that one of your CSS files has a relative reference which is resolving outside of the static directory, and I think that's because you have `static/bootstrap/fonts` where you should just have `static`.

Comment: Ding ding, you get the prize. Actually, I only posted the one staticfile dir I thought was at issue, but I had a path for each subdirectory, and NONE of them should have been there, and they should NOT have had os.path in them. I took them out and it works fine. The os.path join is only for defining 'static'. I don't know what I was thinking when I set it up that way, I must have been drunk. Thx.